# Is it safe to store admin login hardcoded into a php script?

Tags: php, security

I was thinking something really trivial like:

```
if ($email == 'mymail@example.com' && pass == '&2r2KdC#i%$$e2r8'){
    //do login
}
```

Was wondering if this open to possible hacks or exploit, but could not think of any. Since it will be just my login it would not make sense to use a whole database to store only that. I'll use database to store users login. I know it sound stupid to have users with less privileges stored securely in a database and admin login hardcoded, but is it really less secure?

Comment: it's always a bad idea to store unencrypted passwords.  if anyone hacks your hosting, he will have everything with this information

Comment: If your server get exposed and someone access to this file, he'll be able to use those credentials.

Comment: If you're going to use a database, use it now. **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Better identify every user with a "role" column and a simple ACL system. This is bad for all the reason that others already said and also because if you want to change credentials you must change the code. But primarily because is a bad practice :)

Comment: @KonstantinMezentsev if someone hacks my server also encrypted password would be unsafe, sicne they will see what was used to encrypt can simply change the hash or encrypted password with one they generate. My question was to point if it is more likely to have a database exposed or a vpn with ssh disabled.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll be using 7.x PHP was reading about that hashing not if would still be a good idea or if I should just encrypt the password, but again this will have the space for stealing the masterpassword used, so probably hashing is better, what solution should I use with version 7.x instead?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo do you mean similarly to what Wordpress does? Is ACL safe? Like if they access my database they can simply give themselves admin role like you can do with Wordpress in fact.

Comment: I gues you could change that line to `if (sha1($email) == 'bd0a12da78a84af0e89a53352afdcdb9f2312970' && password_verify($pass, '$2y$10$plbWyPkGGhIdCLWSK./LPeY2Dgz6oepnSlZIARxXdAzYBcpCFYLbK'))` :)

Comment: @Pernicious ACL is a standard to make this work, there are different open library that can help you ( eg. https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-permissions-acl/usage/ ). If a user can change his role value on DB, it means there are some problem xD

Comment: With PHP 7 you are better off using the methods provided by PHP.

Comment: @verjas at what point I pull data from the database and how do I know what record to pull if everything is hashed?

Comment: In my comment I was just making a suggestion in case you are going to *hardcode* admins' credentials (or database login credentials) inside a PHP file - you might as well hash them.

Comment: @verjas just found this claiming sha1 is no longer secure, post is from 2017, is that real? https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/at-deaths-door-for-years-widely-used-sha1-function-is-now-dead/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for people to get things from a database without permission, via ways like sql injection if data is not sanitized properly. It is also possible for people to get your php source code, via ways such as having access to your server (e.g. your shell/ftp account), which is quite unlikely assuming that the server is decent enough and you're keeping your credentials for getting into the server safe enough. Do understand that being being a victim of sql injection is a far more likely than people obtaining your php code. (It is also possible that you accidentally did something wrong such as changing the file extension that outputted those lines, the same goes for accidentally writing a wrong query for sql though) There are many more ways things can go wrong of course but here I am just listing out some common problems.

Also, it is worth noting that your database credentials are probably in your php code too, meaning that if they somehow have access to your source code, they most probably can access your database too.

However, I believe the biggest problem is not with where you put the password, it is how you store it. Passwords should **not** be stored as how they are, instead, they should first be hashed before they're stored, then when you want to check if a password is correct, you hash that password too and check it with the hash you stored. It is very dangerous to simply store unhashed passwords, since if someone somehow has access to them, it poses a huge security threat to your users, some users may use this same passwords for multiple places that someone can have access to all those places (this is very bad you shouldn't do this, but there are people to do this). However, if the passwords are hashed, even if someone somehow has access to all of the hashes, they still won't know the actual passwords.

Comment: nice explanation! +1

Comment: "*then when you want to check if a password is correct, you hash that password too and check it with the hash you stored.*" No, you cannot do this with PHP. YOu cannot check hash on hash, that is not the way the mechanism works.

Comment: For php, you hash with a salt, to avoid ppl using a rainbow table. Simplifying the idea up there for those unfamiliar with the idea of hashing. Also, it's not that you **cannot** do that. In fact you can, but you **don't** do that, since there are the dangers of a rainbow table, and php provides excellent functions like password_hash and password_verify.

Comment: Also, technically, you are still hashing the password and checking it with the string in your database, that hash actually consists of the salt, the cost, the algorithm, and the hash, what you actually do is you add that salt to the input password, hash it using that algorithm with that cost, and checking it against the actual hash. However, you don't need to implement any of these yourself as it's all done by password_verify, but i do hope that you understand that the basic principal is still checking the hashed password against the has you have.

Comment: if they can read my php files, where should I store database credentials?

Comment: They shouldn't be able to read your php files unless something is seriously wrong.